# What would be the best way to read all records from a specific Database and print them?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I'm struggling right now trying to figure out how I should read all records from at specific database table and print them out on website. I have a 'newsfeed' section on my website. And I want to show all the news ordered by newest. My problem is not how to connect and select from the database and store the data in an array.

My problem is where to do it, and how? In the same file as where the news are shown, or in an external file which will be included? How should I do it in the external file, if so?

I have a file called 'functions.php', which is included on every single page. It look's like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();
}

function loggedIn(){
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($_SESSION['user_id'] != "")){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

if(loggedIn()){
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$user_first_name = $_SESSION['user_first_name'];
$user_last_name = $_SESSION['user_last_name'];
$user_newsletter = $_SESSION['user_first_name'];
}

?>
```

Should it be here I open the mysqli connection and store the data and how?

```
mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word, $database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";
news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($query); while($news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { display $news_data }` Read the friendly [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect and close connection in the php file you are using for displaying newsfeed. 
You can make a foreach loop like this:

```
mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word, $database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";

 //start table here
 while($news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     //create html table content here
}

//close html table and db connection
```

another method  is making a mapping and use a tablemakerFromArray function:

```
 mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word, $database);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";

 $table_content_array=array('');
 $i++;
 while($news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $table_conntent_array[$i][your_first_key]=$news_data['table_row_about_this_key'];
     .....//other key and rows 
     ......
     $i++;
}

 tableFromArray(table_content_array);//this func. will make keys of array table titles

 public static  function tableFromArray($arr){
    if(count($arr)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ?>
     <table border="1"><tr>
    <?php foreach ($arr[0] as $key => $value) {?>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    <?php }?>
    <tr/>
    <?php
    $i=0;
     foreach ($arr as $item) {?>
    <tr/>
        <?php  foreach ($item as $alan) {?>
            <td><?php echo $alan;?></td>
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
<?php }
```

This is the simplest way to display all data in a table with php.

Comment: Opening and closing a database connection potentially multiple times per request involves unnecessary overhead.  It would still be beneficial to remove the mysqli_connect function to another include that is only evaluated once in the event database connection functions are used/included.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can put the code here, within the If(loggedIn()) condition.

```html
if(loggedIn()){
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$user_first_name = $_SESSION['user_first_name'];
$user_last_name = $_SESSION['user_last_name'];
$user_newsletter = $_SESSION['user_first_name'];
mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word, $database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id";
news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
}
```

of course, there are a lot better ways to organize an PHP project, but for what you have, this works.

Comment: But as mentioned, the file is included in all my files since it has the session_start(); And I guess it wouldn't be smart to open a mysqli connection on the pages I'm not gonna need those kind of informations. So maybe I should make a new function file, include it on the news page after including this function page, and say if(loggedIn){ //Open mysqli connection, get the data, and then close the connection again? }

Answer (score 0):

Its really up to you.  Generally, it is considered a best practice to group similar functionality into seperate files/libraries.  In your case, you could have a file with database related functions in it.  I would suggest, however, that you ensure mysqli_connect is called only once per request, to avoid creating multiple connections.  You could have the mysqli_connect function in a file that gets loaded once per request, and then load the functions file when you need it.  Then, just call the function to query the database as needed.  There may be a time when you just want to connect to the database without actually doing the query, in that case, having the connection logic separate will make your project a little more modular.  There are better ways of handling this, but for a small personal project, this approach shouldn't be an issue.

Based on your other comment, you could have a file containing the mysqli_connect (e.g. mysql_conn.php) function, and another containing your query functions (e.g. mysql_funcs.php).  You could either explicity include mysql_conn.php, or, you could have files that use the mysqli connection include the mysql_conn.php script using require_once, to ensure the connection is only created one time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql_query() to start the SELECT

And you should use DESC or ASC with ORDER BY

```
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
          news_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```